# How do I save a random text from the db in a cookie so the visitor sees it again upon their next visit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I show a visitor some random text from the db (a city name and a phone number). Each visitor will see a random value. I want the same data to be shown to the same visitor (for x days).

Comment: [This][1] answer should help you, I reckon.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770288/storing-retrieving-values-in-a-rails-cookie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @random_text = cookies[:random_text] || Model.find(1).random_text
    cookies[:random_text] ||= @random_text
  end

end
```